# Maven figuring out dependencies

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I am getting started on maven.

So I am starting a spring-boot project and I am trying to include a proprietary dependency from my firm.

So the pom looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>test-project</name>
    <description>Test Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>some-java-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

So when I try to

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I got errors like

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/myhome/git/myproject/src/main/java/my/company/somepkg/Application.java:[3,24] package my.company.somedependency.somepkg does not exist
```

So I realized some packages are missing and went on to add stuff just based out of intuition and looking and pom's from other projects.

My question is:

> How do I approach this problem and get the right dependencies rather
>   than doing stuff on intuition and randomly ?
>
> How do I figure out:
>
> 1. What dependencies are missing ?
> 2. What are transitive and duplicate
>      dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

Well hopefully you don't want people to post a book here ;-)

So some hints that may help:

1: since it is a dependency of your company that is missing I can't tell you. But the error you have is a compilation error - I think Application.class is in the wrong package: `my/company/Application.java:[3,24] package my.company.somepkg`
the "somepkg" part is missing.

2: transitive dependencies are dependencies of dependencies. Often modules rely on hibernate or spring or some other jar. Maven will resolve the required libraries for you using the information in the pom.xml that is deployed along with the jar in the maven repository.
Duplicate dependencies meas you have one dependency twice in you're dependency tree. Maven identifies them with the so called GAV coordinates (groupId, artifactId and version, maybe the classifier as well). If these match maven needs to resolve wich dependency wins.
The usual way is to use that version with the lowest distance. The ones in your own pom have distance 0 (or 1?). dependencies of dependencies have a higher distance. That may be wrong but you can always override them in your own pom this way. Try "`mvn dependency:tree`" where your pom is. It will show what maven sees.

I hope this helped a bit :)